# Vanishing first term of power series

Tags: power-series

I got stuck with the following equation

$ze^{zx} = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} x^{j-1} \frac{z^j}{(j-1)!}$

Have got to this

$z e^{zx} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z(zx)^n}{n!}$

How can I show that the $n=0$ term is zero in the last equation ?

Comment: It's not; it's $z$.

Comment: Your approach seems okay to me! I don’t think the $n=0$ term is zero? It would be $z$ which equals zero when $z=0$.

Comment: Ok.  Have kept the $n=0$ because as you say, the first term is $z$ rather than $0$.  After substituting $n+1=j$, I get the proof.